# Turning this raw pointer situation into a unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have code that looks like this:

```
ISessionUpdater* updater = nullptr;
if (eventName == "test")
    updater = new TestJSONSessionUpdater(doc);
if (eventName == "plus")
    updater = new PlusJSONSessionUpdater(doc);

if (updater)
{
    bool result = updater->update(data);
    delete updater;
    return result;
}
return false;
```

Is there any way to do something like this but with `unique_ptr`?

That is, only ever having 1 call to `update(data)` instead of doing:

```
if(cond)
make unique
call update
end
if(cond)
make unique
call update
end
...
```

Comment: unique_ptr has method reset to change it stored pointer, if that's what you need.

Comment: I mean that, can I just allocate a blank unique_ptr on the stack, one of my ifs fills it, then if it's filled by one of the ifs, execute update function.

Comment: Yes, do it literally the same way.........?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code would be as simple as this:

```
    std::unique_ptr<ISessionUpdater> updater;
    if (eventName == "test")
        updater = std::make_unique<TestJSONSessionUpdater>(doc);
    if (eventName == "plus")
        updater = std::make_unique<PlusJSONSessionUpdater>(doc);

    return updater ? updater->update(data) : false;
```

You can check `std::unique_ptr` almost same way as you do with raw pointer

Notice how calling part could be simplified as a result of using RAII.

Answer (score 4):

You can just assign a new `std::unique_ptr` using `std::make_unique`, and it will destroy the old internal raw pointer if it already has one.

```
std::unique_ptr<ISessionUpdater> updater = nullptr;
if (eventName == "test")
    updater = std::make_unique<TestJSONSessionUpdater>(doc);
if (eventName == "plus")
    updater = std::make_unique<PlusJSONSessionUpdater>(doc);

if (updater)
{
    bool result = updater->update(data);
    return result;
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 3):

`unique_ptr<>` has an [operator bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_bool) conversion that can be used to query if the smart pointer holds an object

```
std::unique_ptr<int> ptr;
if (ptr) // Not yet assigned
   std::cout << "This isn't printed";
```

thus your code becomes

```
std::unique_ptr<ISessionUpdater> updater = nullptr;
if (eventName == "test")
    updater = std::make_unique<TestJSONSessionUpdater>(doc);
if (eventName == "plus")
    updater = std::make_unique<PlusJSONSessionUpdater>(doc);

if (updater) // If this smart pointer owns an object, execute the block
{
    bool result = updater->update(data);
    return result;
}
return false;
```